# Swapping x & y Axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure

Potentially easy matlab question here, but I've searched and can't sort out how to do this.

I've got a variables, which plot like this: [image: Example]

I simple want the x axis to be the y axis and vice versa. How do I swap them?

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard way would be to swap the arguments passed to `plot`:

```
plot(ydata, xdata) %// instead of plot(xdata, ydata)
```

Failing that, you can change the view to rotate the axes:

```
view([90 -90]) %// instead of normal view, which is view([0 90])
```

Comment: The second answer is useful for **area plots**, because as far as I can tell from the documentation there is no way to make the baseline a vertical line.

Commenting with the hope of making this solution easier to find for someone with the same issue that I had.